# MySQL query to return number 'zero' if no results

Tags: mysql, sum, resultset, zero

When selecting a DATE and that date does not exist in my table it currently will return an empty result set.  How can I be able to return the number zero for those empty result sets instead?:

```
    SELECT SUM(TOTAL), SUM(5STAR), STORE, DATE
    FROM `table` WHERE DATE >= '2012-02-24' GROUP BY TOTAL

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)
```

I want to instead return the results of the `SUM(TOTAL)` and `SUM(5STAR)` (if zero rows) as the number zero (0).

FULL TABLE STRUCTURE:

- ID = Primary
- DATE = UNIQUE (date)
- STORE
- 5STAR
- 4STAR
- 3STAR
- 2STAR
- 1STAR
- TOTAL
- FROM = UNIQUE

Comment: Added full table structure.  Perhaps the uniques may cause an issue?  Im new to this so not sure.

Comment: So if you have no row in the result set you want to return one row with 0-s in it? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: This is correct Peter Kiss.  I am displaying in pHp and would like to display 0 for the sums if it doesn't return any results.

Comment: I agree with @PeterKiss, you should handle this on PHP side in some service or facade layer. This kind of logic rarely belongs that close to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to handle the empty result set on the PHP side (count the returned rows). If you want to handle it in the database, you should create a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `mc`.`new_routine` (IN DT DATETIME)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `table` WHERE DATE >= @DT)
THEN
    SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS SumTotal, SUM(5STAR) AS Sum5Star, STORE, `DATE`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE DATE >= @DT
    GROUP BY TOTAL;
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS SumTotal, 0 AS Sum5Star, NULL AS STORE, NULL AS `DATE`;
END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 19):

Try [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(TOTAL),0), COALESCE(SUM(5STAR),0), STORE, DATE
FROM `table` WHERE DATE >= '2012-02-24' GROUP BY TOTAL
```

Answer (score 8):

TRY

```
SELECT
       IFNULL(SUM(TOTAL), 0) AS total,
       IFNULL(SUM(5STAR), 0) AS FiveStar, 
       STORE,
       DATE
FROM `table`
WHERE DATE >= '2012-02-24'
GROUP BY TOTAL
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: also you can try with `COALESCE`