# How to return NULL when result is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query that selects one field and only one row, thus one value.

Is there any way to make it return NULL if the query results in an empty set? Instead of returning zero rows?

I think I need to use something with NOT EXISTS, THEN NULL but not certain about it.

Comment: and why do you want to return null

Comment: @Ankit I'm doing an insert and one of the columns must link to another table with a foreign constraint. An empty result results in FALSE, I need NULL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487963/mysql-query-to-return-number-zero-if-no-results  has near identical code to nwhat you need

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
select
  (Your entire current Select statement goes here) as Alias
from 
  dual
```

`dual` is a built in table with a single row that can be used for purposes like this. In Oracle this was mandatory until 23c. [MySQL supports it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), but you can also just select a single value without specifying a table, like so:

```
select
  (Your entire current Select statement goes here) as Alias
```

In either case you're selecting a single value. This means that:

- If your select returns one value, that value is returned.
- If your select statement returns one column, but no rows, NULL will be returned.
- If your select statement returns multiple columns and/or multiple rows, this won't work and the query fails.

Comment: Genius. This is exactly what I wanted. It works even without `alias`!

Comment: Yeah, alias is not needed, depending on how you process the results. :)

Comment: Also, the 3rd situation is solved with `LIMIT 1` in the inner query :)

Answer (score 19):

An easy way to do this is with aggregation:

```
select max(col)
from t
where <your condition here>
```

This always returns one row.  If there is no match, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: It seems that this returns the `max` of all the columns from `t`. That `max` is not subject to the condition in the where-clause. Or?

Comment: @Guildenstern the aggregation function only applies to rows where the filtering condition has been applied. The order of SQL execution in this case is FROM -> FILTER -> SELECT -> AGGREGATION.

Answer (score 7):

Late reply but I think this is the easiest method:

```
SELECT
   IFNULL((SELECT your query), NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE for example:

`SELECT COALESCE(Field1,NULL) AS Field1 FROM Table1`

**Edit 1:**
sorry i mistake with return field as null not result set,for result set return as null use  Union and Exist Function like this:

```
SELECT NULL AS Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE not EXISTS(SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE Field2>0)
UNION
SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE Field2>0
```

Comment: This still returns zero results if the row does not exist. Not what I want.

Comment: @silkfire sorry i had mistake for return null as field value, please check Edit1

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION with a NOT EXISTS(original where clause)

```
select col1
from mytable
where <some condition>
union
select null
where not exists (
    select *  from mytable
    where <some condition>)
```