LeetCode 619: Biggest Single Number using MySQL
I'm currently working on LeetCode problem 619, "Biggest Single Number," using MySQL. The problem can be found at this link: https://leetcode.com/problems/biggest-single-number/description/
I've written a query for this problem, but I'm unable to obtain the correct answer. I suspect that the issue lies with the order of execution in the query. According to the information I found on GeeksforGeeks, the SQL order of execution should be as follows: FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ...
Based on this order, I believe the correct sequence should be to first retrieve the data from the MyNumbers table, then group it based on the num column, then select only the numbers that appear exactly once, and finally get the maximum value from the selected numbers.
However, despite following this order of execution, I'm not getting the expected result. I'm wondering what could be going wrong with my approach.
Here's the query I currently have:
SELECT Max(num)
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1

expect to get the answer of



num




6



while my output is



Max(num)




1


4


5


6




Please provide a title that summarizes your actual question.

Group by num says to return one row per distinct num.  Aggregate functions such as max work on a group of source row (or all rows, if no group by is specified).  When you need to do two sets of grouping (one to count instances of num, one to find the max of those nums) you need a subquery to do the first grouping

I would be inclined to use an aggregation limit approach here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT num
    FROM MyNumbers
    GROUP BY num
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ORDER BY num DESC
    LIMIT 1
)

SELECT MAX(num)
FROM (
    SELECT num FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
) t;

The aggregation portion of the query will reduce the set to only numbers which appear only once.  The LIMIT and ORDER BY logic will return just the largest number from that intermediate set.

This doesn't work since it doesn't return NULL when there is no number to return. You have to wrap this inside another SELECT statement. If you wrap it in this dual table it will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250243/how-to-return-null-when-result-is-empty

@TeunKruijer The Leet problem statement made no mention of the edge case of an empty table or a non empty table but all numbers are NULL.  Normally, I would not overengineer and take your advice, unless there were a need for it.

Hey Tim, I don't really understand your answer. The Leet problem specifically states that the answer should be NULL if no numbers are found that match the criteria, and your solution doesn't match that. Could you explain further?

@TeunKruijer You were right; I have edited my answer.

Here's one way to solve this: select all numbers that only appear once in a subquery, then select the max value from it:
select max(x.num) as num from (
  select num from MyNumbers group by num having count(*) = 1
) x


simple and awesome ...

First think logically how to do that...
There are few inputs like: 
you have to find the highest single number which occurrence not more than one.  So, first filter the num which have occurrence = 1 and then find max.
So, your solution should be :
 select num
    from MyNumbers
    group by num
    having count(*)=1
    order by num desc
    limit 1

But there is a trick. if there are no such number in the table which occurrence is 1, in that scenario you have to show null value.
For that I like both answers at top.  But here try to resolve some other way.
And, my final answer is:
  SELECT num FROM (
    select num
    from MyNumbers
    group by num
    having count(*)=1
    order by num desc
    limit 1
  ) t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL as num
  order by num desc
  limit 1;

Sample code: db<>diddle
