# Return NULL value when MySQL returned an empty result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as shown below.

```
 select a.ab as new from tab a inner join tab b on a.ab=b.ab
```

When i try to run its showing.

```
  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

because there are no rows for the selected condition.

Actual output i need is.

```
 new
 ----
 NULL
```

So i tried to add this query below.

```
 select COALESCE(a.ab,'') as new from tab a inner join tab b on a.ab=b.ab
```

Still its giving

```
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

So how it is possible to display NULL value when MYSQL returns empty set.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Retuning 0 rows meaning there is no matching record with `inner join`. If you still want some data use `left join` instead.

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487963/mysql-query-to-return-number-zero-if-no-results

Comment: This is a suspicious requirement. Why do you think you need to do this? It points to a logical flaw in your program. You're fundamentally changing the meaning of "number of rows" in your query for a subset of scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the `Outer select`. Encapsulate the query with the `Outer select`, if you want actual `NULL` value from the database in case of 0 rows,

```
SELECT 
    (
      SELECT a.ab 
      FROM 
          tab a INNER JOIN tab b 
           ON a.ab=b.ab
    ) As New;
```

You can use the alternative with `UNION ALL`  and `LIMIT`
as,

```
      SELECT a.ab 
      FROM 
          tab a INNER JOIN tab b 
           ON a.ab=b.ab
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT NULL
      LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the result is null when you have 0 rows try this statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB AS A INNER JOIN TAB AS B ON A.AB = B.AB )
BEGIN
     SELECT A.AB AS NEW FROM TAB AS A INNER JOIN TAB AS B ON A.AB = B.AB 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL AS NEW
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return null instead of empty result, try this:

```
select (select a.ab as new from tab a inner join tab b on a.ab=b.ab);
```

If you need the result column to be named new, add a new at the end:

```
select (your entire mysql query) new;
```

Explanation:
Select without from is not standard conforming SQL. Nevertheless it works in many databases.
Some databases like oracle require `from dual`.
MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)).
When there is no rows, select without from clause will return null.